# PayPal Payment status "Pending" - no IPN on clearing

Tags: paypal-ipn

Something strange seems to have happened on a client's e-commerce site in the last few months.

When a buyer completes a sale using a credit or debit card instead of a PayPal account, the transaction status (as communicated via the IPN) is "Pending". In the PayPal account the transaction is described as "Interchange plus – settlement hold".

Typically two days later the payment clears. But no IPN is sent to the website cart to confirm that this has happened, leaving the e-commerce system in the dark about the payment status.

Is this correct behaviour? It seems that it almost makes the IPN useless as a reporting method.

Lots of similar problems reported but not the same as ours: it's nothing to do with multi-currency or conversion and this is a live site, not a sandbox (using Mal's E-Commerce) which was working fine until this summer. (I note that Interchange Plus was added to PayPal T&Cs in June.)

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal acknowledged that this is a problem.

I posted this on PayPal's community boards and (eventually) got a response:

> "We are aware of this and raised this internally. At the moment the
>   system doesn't send an IPN in this scenario. There is an ask in with
>   our development teams to have an IPN issued once the IC+ payment
>   clears, unfortunately I don't have an ETA though"

See https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/IPN-PDT/IPN-sends-Pending-status-and-nothing-further/m-p/1119362?profile.language=en

They have confirmed that switching to the 'blended' fees structure will stop this happening. So that would seem to be the answer for now.